# How to Tell If an Object Has Been Garbage Collected

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

How I can know to tell if an Object has been garbage collected or not?

Comment: The 'duplicate' question is not very specific, so reopened. This asks a specific question and has a specific answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to [this](http://csharp.2000things.com/2012/12/11/733-how-to-tell-if-an-object-has-been-garbage-collected/):

You normally can’t tell whether an object has been garbage collected by using some reference to the object–because once you have a reference to the object, it won’t be garbage collected.

You can instead create a weak reference to an object using the WeakReference object.  The weak reference is one that won’t be counted as a reference, for purposes of garbage collection.

In the code below, we check before and after garbage collection to show that a Dog object is garbage collected.

```
Dog dog = new Dog("Bowser");

WeakReference dogRef = new WeakReference(dog);
Console.WriteLine(dogRef.IsAlive);

dog = null;
GC.Collect();

Console.WriteLine(dogRef.IsAlive);
```

[image]

Comment: This trick is useful in the case of unit testing some hand-made container with a „Clear“ method.

Comment: This trick can fail in the case of debug mode: all local objects are „hooked“ until the end of the method. So, If you are writing some kind of unit test, the above code should be wrapped into a method and the weak reference (as well as GC.Collect() call) must be checked after the wrapper invocation.

Comment: I had to use these three lines to get it to work in GitHub actions, though it worked locally just fine:

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();